# Deployment of Provider Hosted Addin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, 2016, provider-hosted-app, visual-studio-2015

I created a Provider Hosted Addin for SharePoint Server 2016 using Visual Studio 2015. All went well. When I right click solution and chose Deploy Solution, Visual Studio only display 'Deployment Succeeded' but it does not redirects me to the below page where I can install my Addin to SharePoint Developer site.

[image]